# How to make Multplication table using Double for loops?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a **multiplication** table using **double for loops** from 1 to 10.i can do use single for loops but i have no idea about using double for loops.
here is my some code

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    let res = 1 + ' x ' + i + ' = ' + i * 1
    console.log(res);

    for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

    }
}
```

please let me know this how can I do it

Comment: just put everything inside the second for loop...

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {
    for(j=1;j<=10;j++) {
       console.log(`${i} x ${j} = ${i*j}`);
    }
}
```

It will print the multiplication table to the console.
I am using ES6 template strings to avoid joining strings with '+'. Feel free to use the normal string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

**Version 0:**

If you want each multiplication on a separate row (as in the original code), you can modify that code to print all products of pairs:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
        let res = i + ' x ' + j + ' = ' + i * j;
        console.log(res);
    }
}
```

The nested for loop means that for each value of `i` (in `[1,10]`) you are trying each value of `j` (in `[1,10]`) and executing the two lines in the middle (calculating the result and printing it) for a total of 100 lines.

Result:

```
1 x 1 = 1
1 x 2 = 2
1 x 3 = 3
1 x 4 = 4
1 x 5 = 5
1 x 6 = 6
1 x 7 = 7
1 x 8 = 8
1 x 9 = 9
1 x 10 = 10
2 x 1 = 2
2 x 2 = 4
2 x 3 = 6
2 x 4 = 8
...
```

**Version 1:**

If you want the result to display in an actual table layout you'll need to modify the code a bit more to build up each row of the result and then print the row:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    let row = []; // Start with an empty row
    for (let j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
        row.push(i * j); // Add an i * j pair to the row
    }
    // Print the row with tab (`\t) characters between each item.
    console.log(row.join("\t"));
}
```

Result:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18  20
3   6   9   12  15  18  21  24  27  30
4   8   12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40
5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
6   12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60
7   14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70
8   16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80
9   18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90
10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      let res = i + ' x ' + (j+1) + ' = ' + (i * (j+1));
      document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML += res+"<br/>";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```